# Foreign key constraint fails in creating child row in NestJS with MySQL and XAMPP

Tags: mysql, nestjs

i am using the framework nestjs.

So this is the error :

> QueryFailedError: ER_NO_REFERENCED_ROW_2: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`cogblabelle`.`experience`, CONSTRAINT `FK_dda75dd68256494642e279acd65` FOREIGN KEY (`candidatId`) REFERENCES `candidats` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION)

I have two tables, "candidats" and "experiences" , what i try to do is :  everytime i log with candidat i can creat an experience, so in database i will have in table `experieces` the `id` of `candidat` that created it.

When i do this in postman after log in i get the token, and try to create an experiece i had this error;

please tell me what's the problem can be ??

here i have the entities where i create the tables :

```
import { Entity, PrimaryGeneratedColumn, Column, OneToMany  } from 'typeorm';

import { ExperienceEntity } from './experience.entity';




@Entity('candidats')
export class CandidatEntity{

    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id : number;

    @Column()
    nom : string;

    @Column()
    prenom : string;

    @Column()
    datenais : Date;

    @Column()
    tel : string;

    @Column()
    sexe : CandidatStatus;

    @Column()
    adresse : string;

    @Column()
    email : string;

    @Column()
    mdp : string;

    @Column()
    salt : string;

    @OneToMany(() => ExperienceEntity, (experience) => experience.candidat 

    
    
    )
    experiences : ExperienceEntity[]
    


}

export enum CandidatStatus {
    M = 'masculin',
    F = 'feminin',
  }
```

```
import { Entity, PrimaryGeneratedColumn, Column, ManyToOne } from 'typeorm';
import { CandidatEntity } from '../Entity/candidat.entity';


@Entity('Experience')
export class ExperienceEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column({ type: 'date' })
  datedebut: Date;

  @Column({ type: 'date' })
  datefin: Date;

  @Column()
  intituleposte: string;

  @Column()
  nomentreprise: string;

  @Column()
  lieu: string;

  @Column()
  service: string;

  @Column()
  status: ExperienceStatus;


  @ManyToOne( () => CandidatEntity, (candidat)=> candidat.experiences 
 
  )
  candidat : CandidatEntity

  @Column()
  candidatId : number;

   

}

export enum ExperienceStatus {
  PosteActuel = 'ACTUEL',
  AncienPoste = 'ANCIEN',
}
```

here this is the controller and service

```
import { Controller, Get, Post, Body, ValidationPipe, Patch, Param , Delete, UseGuards} from '@nestjs/common';
import { ExperienceService } from './experience.service';
import { CreatExperienceDto } from 'src/DTO/create.experience.dto';
import { ExperienceStatus } from 'src/Entity/experience.entity';
import { ExperienceStatusValidationPipe } from 'src/pipes/ExperienceStatusValidation.pipe';
import { AuthGuard } from '@nestjs/passport';
import { Candidat } from '../auth/candidat.decorator';
import { CandidatEntity } from '../Entity/candidat.entity';
 


@Controller('experiences')
@UseGuards(AuthGuard('jwt'))
export class ExperienceController {

    constructor(private experienceservice : ExperienceService){

    }

    @Get()
    getAllExperiences(@Candidat() candidat : CandidatEntity) {


        return this.experienceservice.getAllExperiences(candidat);
    }

    @Post()
    createNewExperience(@Body(ValidationPipe) data : CreatExperienceDto,
                       @Candidat() candidat : CandidatEntity
    ){

       return this.experienceservice.createExperience(data, candidat);
    }
```

```
import { Injectable, InternalServerErrorException } from '@nestjs/common';
import {InjectRepository} from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import exp from 'constants';
import { CreatExperienceDto } from 'src/DTO/create.experience.dto';
import { ExperienceEntity, ExperienceStatus } from 'src/Entity/experience.entity';
import { Repository } from 'typeorm';
import { CandidatEntity } from '../Entity/candidat.entity';
import { NotFoundException} from '@nestjs/common';

@Injectable()
export class ExperienceService {

    constructor(@InjectRepository(ExperienceEntity) private repo: Repository<ExperienceEntity>) {}

   async getAllExperiences(candidat : CandidatEntity){

        const query = this.repo.createQueryBuilder('experience');
        query.where(`experience.candidatId = :candidatId`, {candidatId : candidat?.id});

        try {
           return await query.getMany();
        } catch (error) {
            throw new NotFoundException('no experience found');

        }
    }

    async createExperience (createxpdto : CreatExperienceDto, candidat: CandidatEntity){

        const exper = new ExperienceEntity();
        const {datedebut,datefin, intituleposte, nomentreprise, lieu, service}= createxpdto;
        exper.datedebut = datedebut;
        exper.datefin = datefin;
        exper.intituleposte = intituleposte;
        exper.nomentreprise = nomentreprise;
        exper.lieu = lieu;
        exper.service = service;
        exper.status = ExperienceStatus.PosteActuel;
        exper.candidatId = candidat?.id;
        
             this.repo.create(exper);

         try {

            return await this.repo.save(exper);

         } catch (error) {
            
            console.log(error.stack);
            throw new InternalServerErrorException('Quelque chose ne vas pas bien');
         }
        
    }
```

Please help me //